# Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2

Tags: laravel

Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.
Please Check My query :

```
foreach ($mail as $value ){
                $data['rec'] = json_decode(json_encode($value),true);
            }

                Mail::send(array('html' => 'mail'),  $data, function($message) use($data)
            {
                // print_r($email);
                $message->to($data->email);
            });
```

Comment: You have several variables that are confusing at first glance. You include `$data` in the closure, but it's not used. You have variables `$email` and `$unit` in the closure that don't exist anywhere else.

Comment: PLease explain clearly

Comment: I don't really think I can make that any clearer...

Comment: Now you can check the code

Comment: Is `$data->email` a valid email address?

Comment: I got a solution

Comment: @Lingham, perhaps your solution should be posted within the answers section for others to refer to in future...

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($mail as $value ){
                $data['rec'] = json_decode(json_encode($value),true);
                print_r($data['rec']['email']);
                Mail::send(array('html' => 'mail'),  $data, function($message) use($data)
                         {
                            <!-- print_r($data->email); -->
                          $message->to($data['rec']['email'])->subject($data['rec']['invoice']);
                        });

            }
```